# LibGDX use java.util.stream.Stream in core folder?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to make a default stream function in my lib GDX game. I followed some instructions on adding to my android gradle project but ofc that only lets me use it in my android project.
How can I use it in my core folder?

Android gradle build file:

```
defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    compileOptions {
        // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    dependencies {
        coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.9'
    }
```

Core gradle build:

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]

eclipse.project.name = appName + "-core"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the source compatibility in your gradle file to `1.8`, since Streams are part of java-8:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html

> Since:
> 1.8

So your `build.gradle` file should look like this:

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]

eclipse.project.name = appName + "-core"
```

**Note**: After this change your game will require a java-8 JRE to be run.

Comment: Yeah I tried that and got an error I'm not at my desktop atm but I'll double check my JRE before getting back to you. Thanks for helping me with another libgdx problem 

Comment: Okay so, I checked my JRE and I'm running 11.0.10+9. Even though the project didn't sync I tried to build it anyway to see if maybe I could get some other errors. Well I did. And It looks like I needed to update my iOS build.gradle files sourceCompatibility to '1.8' as well. After that I was able to sync and build. Thanks again.